# Django exclude follower in query

Tags: python, django, subquery, django-queryset

I have 2 models, userProfile and relationship. Users can follow each other and the relation is made through the relationship model. Here is the code :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique =True)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',symmetrical=False,null=True, blank=True,related_name='related_to')

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='to_people')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)
```

I'm trying to get the list of userProfile excluding the list of userProfile followed by a certain user.
Here is my query:

```
topUsersRecommendation = UserProfile.objects.exclude(id=profile.id,relationships__to_people__from_person = profile).extra(
   select={
    'num_group': """
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM axiom_alto_groupuser gu1
     JOIN axiom_alto_groupuser gu2 on gu1.group_id = gu2.group_id
     WHERE gu2.user_id=axiom_alto_userprofile.id 
     AND gu1.user_id = %d """ % profile.id,
},

).order_by('-num_group')
```

But the exclude doesn't seems to work.
Thank you for your help ^^

Comment: what is the purpose of the `relationship` field on the `UserProfile` model?

Comment: sorry about that I wrote it wrong but in my code it's good thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to `UserProfile` defined as such:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(
    'self',
    blank=True,
    symmetrical=False,
    through='Relationship',
    related_name='followees'
)
```

IIRC you can then do something like this:

```
certain_user = UserProfile.objects.get(slug='Bob')
all_but_certain_user_followees = UserProfile.objects.all().exclude(
    follower = certain_user
)
```

Comment: This is not really helping.